# How to create a DOS batch file that produces an output file with a list of files specified in the batch arguments?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file `batch.bat` that can be executed as follows

```
batch.bat output PDF PNG JPG EPS
```

to produce `output.list` that contains

```
filename1.pdf
filename2.pdf
filename3.pdf
filename4.pdf
filename1.png
filename2.png
filename3.jpg
filename4.eps
```

Note that the first two arguments are the only mandatory arguments. My effort is as follows but I think it uses a barbaric programming technique because `%1` is used to prepare a new output file and unavoidably it is used again in the first iterate that does nothing.

```
rem batch.bat
echo off

rem %1 represents the output file name
rem the remaining args represent file extension

dir /b *.%1 > %1.list

for %%x in (%*) do (dir /b *.%%x >> %1.list)
```

How to smartly create a DOS batch file that produces an output file with a list of files specified in the batch arguments?

Edit:

I need the batch file because it will be called from the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newread\myfile
\newcount\TotalFiles

\AtBeginDocument
{
    \immediate\write18{IterateFiles.bat \jobname\space pdf png jpg eps}
    \openin\myfile=\jobname.list\relax
}

\AtEndDocument
{
    \closein\myfile
}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\loop
    \read\myfile to \mydata
    \unless\ifeof\myfile
    \filename@parse{\mydata}
    \section*{\mydata}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{\filename@base}
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
\repeat
\makeatother

\section*{Summary}
There are \the\TotalFiles\ files in total.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice command to help you here:

> SHIFT
>
> Changes the position of replaceable parameters in a batch file.
>
> SHIFT [/n]
>
> If Command Extensions are enabled the SHIFT command supports the /n
>   switch that tells the command to start shifting at the nth argument,
>   where n may be between zero and eight. For example:
>
> SHIFT /2
>
> would shift %3 to %2, %4 to %3, etc. and leave %0 and %1 unaffected.

So to adapt your code to use `shift`:

```
REM ...

REM need to create output file name here as it will be gone after the first iteration
SET output_file=%1.list
COPY NUL %output_file%

:LOOP
REM jump out of the loop if there are no more parameters are present
IF "%2"=="" GOTO :EOF

REM 
DIR /b *.%2 >> %output_file%
SHIFT
GOTO :LOOP
```

This will always use the second parameter (`%2`), but after each iteration all parameter values supplied in command line will be shifted one to the left.

Comment: How to create a new output file whenever this batch is executed?

Comment: You can create an empty file with `COPY NUL %output_file%`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler batch solution

```
@echo off
setlocal
copy nul "%~1.list"
set "go="
for %%x in (%*) do if defined go (dir /b *.%%x >>"%~1.list") else set go=1
```

Comment: EDIT - Now clears the contents of the output at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

WMI command called within a batch will achieve the same thing:

```
wmic /output:"output.list" /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path CIM_LogicalFile where "Extension='PDF' or Extension='PNG' or Extension='JPG' or Extension='EPS'" get FileName,Extension /all /format:csv
```

Comment: What is WMI? It's not a program that comes with Windows.